# Let $x, y \in \mathbb{Z}$. Show that $x = y \mod n$ if and only if $x + n\mathbb{Z} = y+n\mathbb{Z}$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, discrete-mathematics

Let $x, y$ be integers. Show that if $x = y\mod n$, then $x + n\mathbb{Z} = y+n\mathbb{Z}$, and conversely, if $x+n\mathbb{Z}=y+n\mathbb{Z}$, then $x = y\mod n$.

I have no a clue on how to prove this! Please help.

Comment: You should begin by *carefully* writing down the definitions of every symbol you've used.

Answer (score 1):

By [definition](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Congruence.html),  $x\equiv y\pmod n\iff x-y=a\cdot n$ where $a$ is some integer

I believe you have meant $x+nZ_1=y+nZ_2\iff x-y=n(Z_2-Z_1)$ where $Z_2,Z_1$ are integers

Comment: Z is the set of integers. I don't know how to put that in latex form.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is way late, but here's a no-frills proof.

$(\Rightarrow)$: Suppose $x = y \mod n$. Then $n \mid x - y$, and so $nk = x - y$ for some $k \in \mathbb{Z}$. Hence $x = nk + y$ and $y = x - nk$.

We show $x+n\mathbb{Z} = y + n\mathbb{Z}$ by subsets.

$(\subseteq)$: Let $a \in x + n\mathbb{Z}$. So $a = x + nz$ for some $z \in \mathbb{Z}$. Thus,

\begin{align}
a &= x + nz \\
&= y + nk + nz \\
&= y + n(k - z) \\
&\in y + n\mathbb{Z}\textrm{.}
\end{align}

So $x + n\mathbb{Z} \subseteq y + n\mathbb{Z}$.

$(\supseteq)$: Similar.

Thus, $x + n\mathbb{Z} = y + n\mathbb{Z}$.

$(\Leftarrow)$: Suppose $x + n\mathbb{Z} = y + n\mathbb{Z}$. Since $\mathbb{Z}$ is nonempty, there exists $a \in x + n\mathbb{Z}$, and so $a = x + nz$ for some $z \in \mathbb{Z}$. But $a$ is also a member of $y + n\mathbb{Z}$, and so $a = y + nw$ for some $w \in \mathbb{Z}$. Hence,

\begin{align}
x + nz &= y + nw \\
x - y &= nw - nz \\
x - y &= n(w - z)
\end{align}

and so $n \mid x - y$. Thus, $x = y \mod n$.